# Pressing a headset button and triggering an event?

Tags: android

I have an earphone, headset. It, vertically, has the buttons, increase volume, middle button, lower volume.

By pressing the middle button, it opens the spotify and plays music, even with the screen off or the phone locked.

I would like to do this for an application of mine, when press this middle button, this application trigger an event, is it possible? Or, press one of the volume buttons and trigger an event.

It is possible? If yes, is there any example, source code, with this application?

EDIT:

The code did not work:

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        IntentFilter filtro = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);//"android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"
        MediaButtonIntentReceiver r = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
        filtro.setPriority(1000); //this line sets receiver priority
        registerReceiver(r, filtro);
    }


}
```

Broadcast:

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            return;
        }
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event == null) {
            return;
        }
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            toDo();
            Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        abortBroadcast();
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aula.bob.headset">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class extending Broadcast Receiver in your App:

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() {
super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
String intentAction = intent.getAction();
if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
    return;
}
KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
if (event == null) {
    return;
}
int action = event.getAction();
if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
// do something
    Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
abortBroadcast();
}
}
```

And in your Activity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);//"android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"
MediaButtonIntentReceiver r = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
filter.setPriority(10000); //this line sets receiver priority
registerReceiver(r, filter);

}
}
```

Define your Receiver in Android Manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: Would this also work with the application closed or at least in the background?

Comment: Yeah it should.

Comment: Set priority to 10000 not 1000.

Comment: Yes! I've tried with this priority too. With spotify installed, it opens the spotify, without spotify installed, nothing happens. Android 6.0.1

Comment: I am pressing the button that opens the googlenow in the longpress

Comment: The code I have posted above is only set for "Volume Down" button and when you will press the volume down button it'll just show you a Toast. You can get events for other buttons in the same way. First of all just check is it working for "Volume Down" button. Is it showing a Toast or not.

Comment: It does not work, it simply lowers the volume, even with the activity open.

Comment: I'll look into it again and will get back to you.

Comment: Thank you @Zohaib